# Unable to find Gradle tasks to build: [:]. Build mode: ASSEMBLE. Tests: All

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am going through Android Tutorials to learn how to code. I haven't dealt with Gradle before. So I am having a hard time understanding the error codes. I build a very basic app.

When I go to build and click `Make Project` I get a weird error at the bottom:

[image: Android Studio]

And it doesn't do much after that. I am not sure if that is a warning that I can ignore or not. When it comes to Android dev, I am just a spring chicken.

EDIT: If i run the `gradle.bat` file from the command line I get this:

```
C:\git\Others\android-code\MyTestApp>gradlew.bat
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\git\Others\android-code\MyTestApp\build.gradle' line: 7

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.4.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.4.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Google
    MavenRepo
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6m 14s
```

Any help would be appreicated. I cant even get through the tutorial with these errors!

Comment: Been dealing with this too no success, last time i ran inti this was because i was in south america not sure if they block it or something...man this is pretty sucky .... pretty misleading messages with no clear solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a proxy I suggest You look at this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/239471023).

Pay attention to it:

> Also I had clean my proxy in gradle.properties. Don't know if there is
> any check that I have left.

> Thx I finally found the problem:
>
> After I set the proxy in Android Studio, it set the proxy to the file
> in /User/.gradle/gradle.properties
> Thanks again for your help and sorry for the bothering.